# PHP 5.3 on Fedora 18

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fedora

I'm running F18 on my devel machine and I NEED to run PHP 5.3.* (best 5.3.6) on it. F18 doesn't have it in its own repositories and I can't build PHP 5.3 from source because of buggy libxml2-2.9 in F18. I searched internet for two days and didn't fine a solution to my problem. I'm desperate, if anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please read the [about] in particular what SF is not about. This would be better asked on [su] or [so].

Comment: Just run an EL6 virtual machine. The target environment isn't going to be Fedora 18 after all.

Comment: To complement @MichaelHampton's comment, you can install [CentOS](http://www.centos.org) as a faithful RHEL clone.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step as below.

```
#(as root) yum install pcre-devel ncurses-devel httpd-devel mysql-devel zlib-devel libcurl-devel readline-devel mysql-connector-c++-devel openssl-devel
```

Grab the source from PHP.net and extract it.

```
#(as root)./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --enable-inline-optimization --enable-libxml --enable-session --enable-xml --enable-hash --with-pear --with-apxs2 --with-layout=GNU --enable-filter --with-pcre-regex --with-zlib --enable-simplexml --enable-dom --with-openssl --enable-pdo --with-pdo-sqlite --with-readline --with-iconv --with-sqlite3 --disable-phar --enable-xmlwriter --enable-xmlreader --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d --with-mysql=/usr --with-libdir=lib64 --with-pdo-mysql --with-gd --with-curl --with-config-file-path=/etc
```

make, and make install

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with installing CentOS on different machine. Fedora is too much "up to date" to temper with old packages on it. For all of you who try to do it. Forget it! You will spent countless hours trying to solve it. Quickest way to solve it is to install different older distro.